# Google App Engine Make a rollback with appcfg.sh

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to make a rollback due a deploy failed, my server code is on java, and also i'm using App Engine Eclipse PlugIn for. my appcfg.sh file is located at `/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.5/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.5/bin/appcfg.sh`

---

but i get "Command not Found" when i try this `sudo /Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.5/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.5/bin/appcfg.sh rollback /Documents/workspace/server_side/war`

I can't realize what's wrong. i don`t know if is the right appcfg, because there is appcfg.cmd and appcfg.sh, i'm using an imac(Unix enviro) so i use the appcfg.sh to made the rollback. i've tried in several different ways. and nothing good happen. maybe i'm missing something.
thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run `/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.5/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.5/bin/appcfg.sh`  without any arguments?

Comment: Nothing, just says command not found. like this `sudo: /Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.5/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.5/bin/appcfg.sh: command not found`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does not have execute permission by default:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 yorkw  staff   558 11 Dec 06:01 appcfg.sh
```

Run `chmod 755 appcfg.sh` to change the permission:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 yorkw  staff   558 11 Dec 06:01 appcfg.sh
```

Then you should be able to run it in terminal.

Comment: Hi @yorkw, I've typed `chmod 755 appcfg.sh`, the issue still happen. it says `-bash: appcfg: command not found` when i try to rollback.

Comment: type `cd /Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.5/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.5/bin/`, then type `chmod 755 appcfg.sh`.

Comment: this is the output:                                                  `total 64
-rw-r--r--  1 useami03  staff   286 Feb  5 12:18 appcfg.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 useami03  staff   558 Feb  5 12:18 appcfg.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 useami03  staff   368 Feb  5 12:18 dev_appserver.cmd
-rw-r--r--  1 useami03  staff   636 Feb  5 12:18 dev_appserver.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 useami03  staff   940 Feb  5 12:18 endpoints.cmd
-rw-r--r--  1 useami03  staff  1100 Feb  5 12:18 endpoints.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 useami03  staff   196 Feb  5 12:18 google_sql.cmd
-rw-r--r--  1 useami03  staff   479 Feb  5 12:18 google_sql.sh`

Comment: @AlexSanchez, if you are in that directory, try `./appcfg.sh`.

Comment: it works, thanks, but i'm still missing some arguments to commit the rollback i think.

Comment: i'd like to continue on chat.

Comment: @AlexSanchez, chat room [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25249/room-for-yorkw-and-alexsanchez).

Comment: @AlexSanchez Could we have so the right solution at the problem? Becuase i'm still stuck

Comment: You also need to elevate the permissions for run_java.sh. Do 'chmod +x run_java.sh'

Comment: I also had to create app password. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Answer (score 5):

I also encountered the same problem as the original poster of this question, but I still got a permission denied error when attempting to rollback, even after changing the permissions of the appcfg.sh file.

It turned out I also needed to chmod 755 run_java.sh (located in the same directory as appcfg.sh), and then I was able to rollback without problems.

I thought I would post this in case anyone encountered the same set of issues that I did.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who stumbles upon this and wants more detail...

In Terminal go to GAE-SDK-PATH/bin (where appcfg.sh is located) for instance:

> /Applications/Eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.3/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.3/bin

You may not have enabled permissions with appcfg.sh, so do what @yorkw suggested if you are getting 'Permission Denied', in the bin directory type:

> chmod 755 appcfg.sh

then to rollback type

> ./appcfg.sh --email=PROJECT_EMAIL --passin rollback ROOT_PROJECT_FOLDER/war

You will be prompted to enter the password for the project email, and then it should work!
Google doc: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you made the same silly oversight as me and left out "sh" at the beginning?
i.e.

```
sh /Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.5/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.5/bin/appcfg.sh rollback /Documents/workspace/server_side/war
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands on ***OSX***. Note the ***appcfg.sh doesn't have execute permission*** by default so you need to add it via **chmod**.

```
cd /Users/Labuser/Downloads/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.22/bin

chmod 755 appcfg.sh

sh appcfg.sh rollback /Users/Labuser/Ducuments/AndroidWS/AndroidStudioProjects/AndroidProject/modulebackend/src/main/webapp/
```